# iMacro - Using XPATH in TAG Command - Wrong Format of TAG Command

Tags: xpath, tags, command, imacros

I am getting wrong format of TAG command at line 4" of this macro. The strange thing is that when I remove the variable and run the TAG line as a separate macro, it works fine. I even removed the variable and put in 1 in place of it but still the same error in displayed. Can anyone please help? I have searched everywhere for an answer.

```
const L = "\n";
    var pc;
    var bret;
        pc = 1;
        bret = 1;
        while (pc < 16 && bret > 0) {
              iimSet("VAR1",pc)
               bret = iimPlayCode("TAG XPATH=/html/body/form/div[3]/div[7]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[{{!VAR1}}]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/a" + L +
                                  "WAIT SECONDS=3" + L +
                                  "TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=ID:NavLink EXTRACT=TXT"  + L +
                                  "TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=ID:lblTitle EXTRACT:TXT" + L +
                                  "TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=ID:lblPrice EXTRACT:TXT" + L +
                                  "SCREENSHOT TYPE=PAGE FOLDER=* FILE="+pc + L +
                                  "SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=* FILE=wassup.csv" + L +
                                  "BACK");
                pc++;
                }
```

Comment: Which line is line 4" ? Also, does it matter that `iimSet("VAR1",pc)` has no semicolon after it?

Comment: figured it out on my own. This was happening since on line 4 of iimPlayCode, EXTRACT:TXT was mentioned whereas it should be EXTRACT=TXT. @LarsH - Thank you for providing your input. The semicolon was missed by me while transferring code from editor.

Comment: Glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out on my own. This was happening since on line 4 of iimPlayCode, EXTRACT:TXT was mentioned whereas it should be EXTRACT=TXT.

```
const L = "\n";
    var pc;
    var bret;
        pc = 1;
        bret = 1;
        while (pc < 16 && bret > 0) {
              iimSet("VAR1",pc);
               bret = iimPlayCode("TAG XPATH=/html/body/form/div[3]/div[7]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[{{!VAR1}}]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/a" + L +
                                  "WAIT SECONDS=3" + L +
                                  "TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=ID:NavLink EXTRACT=TXT"  + L +
                                  "TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=ID:lblTitle EXTRACT=TXT" + L +
                                  "TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=ID:lblPrice EXTRACT=TXT" + L +
                                  "SCREENSHOT TYPE=PAGE FOLDER=* FILE="+pc + L +
                                  "SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=* FILE=wassup.csv" + L +
                                  "BACK");
                pc++;
                }
```